# how to show 0 data point in visualization when data is missing in data table?

Tags: spotfire

i have one visualization, 
on x-axis i have months of date column, 
on Y-axis i have unique count of issues.
i have 2 filters in text area, 
when i am selecting some values in filter 1 or filter 2 than if count is not available for any month than i need 0 for that month.
Lets suppose i have 5 month(Jan to may) data in my data table, i selected 1 value from filter 1 and 1 value from filter 2, if that combination data is not available for march and April, than trend should show 0 count for march and April.
it is a trend line so if count is not available for any month for selected filters than it should show 0. any lead will help.
TIA

Answer (score 2):

Go to the x-axis settings of your vizualization, click on settings next to your month variable and with the categorical options, choose show all values. If you have a bar chart it will show you the 0 values. In a line chart Spotfire will continue the line as if there are no missing values. In this case you need to add markers to your line.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3Fwc.png):[image: Advanced settings]